# Reactjs: Prevent re-rendering of relocated nodes

Tags: reactjs

I have a gallery of 160 items that are being rendered.  The user is able to sort and group the items in the gallery.  Sorting is basically instantaneous as none of the items get re-rendered.  However, when I group the items React thinks that every item needs to be re-rendered (it doesn't even look like shouldComponentUpdate is called) which is taking a few seconds.

Here is what the basic structure looks like:

```
<div key="gallery">
   <div key="item1" ... />
   <div key="item2" ... />
   <div key="item3" ... />
</div>
```

Then after grouping it becomes:

```
<div key="gallery">
   <div key="group1" .../>
   <div key="group1-gallery">
     <div key="item1" ... />
     <div key="item2" ... />
   </div>   
   <div key="group2" .../>
   <div key="group2-gallery">
     <div key="item3" ... />
   </div>  
</div>
```

The items themselves are not changed at all. Is there anyway to convince React to re-use the existing items?  Is there a different structure I should be using or some other way to provide a hint to React?

Comment: When you use the browser's profiler, where is the hot spot? I wouldn't expect it to take several seconds regardless. Given the significant changes you've made to the DOM structurally, I'm not sure there's much you can do to preserve elements during the grouping.

Comment: 160 is not much. The problem must lie somewhere else. Regarding hinting React, I also don't think that's possible given you've altered the tree.

Comment: Regarding your performance issue, have you tried using the production build of React? (`process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"`). Some computations like propTypes validation can take up a lot of time when dealing with hundreds of components.

Comment: Thanks,I didn't think the development build would add as much overhead as it does. Changing to production definitely helped a lot.  Looks like the last hot spot is that each gallery item needs to subscribe to events. This and the related teardown is taking about 20% of the remaining render time. I could subscribe at a higher level, but it is only the item that needs re-render and the next place that makes sense is about 4 levels up.  Seems fragile to pass props down the chain that far.